# Error when cloning a repository mozilla-central

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, thunderbird

I get this error when just cloning the mozilla source code repository, can you tell me what the problem is?

[image: erorr in console]

or

When cloning via TortoiseHg GUI I get the following error

- The remote host forcibly terminated the existing connection
  code 255

[image: check picture]

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of text, they are very hard to read, impossible for users of screen readers and you can't search for the content. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: Show **as text** result of `hg clone -v --debug ...`

Comment: Didn't you already post this question previously?

Comment: When using 
'hg clone -v --debug https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central source'
Cloning ends with the following lines:
...
adding b2g/config/gaia.json revisions
bundle2-input-part: total payload size 2000158669
transaction abort!
rollback completed
(sent 2 HTTP requests and 484 bytes; received 5269 bytes in responses)
abort: "check screen"

Comment: `hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central` works for me. It's probably a network issue. Try from another location.